# Qt 5.6.2(msvc2015-32bit) model/view-readonly example unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qtableview

I experiment with the '[readonly](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html)' model/view example:

examples/widgets/tutorials/modelview/1_readonly/mymodel.cpp

When I change it to this ...

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "mymodel.h"

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent)
    :QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
   return 2;
}

int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return 22000000;
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << QString("R%1C%2")
                .arg(index.row() + 1)
                .arg(index.column() +1);

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
       return QString("R%1C%2")
                   .arg(index.row() + 1)
                   .arg(index.column() +1);
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

... QTableView from the main.c keeps asking for 'index' beyond the cells it is showing :
[image]

However, when I change return value to 21000000

```
int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return 21000000;
}
```

... it works as expected :

[image]

What is so special about the number 22000000 ?

Thank you.

Comment: 100 times that number exceeds the range of int32. And each column is approximately 100px wide, it seems. This might also screw up the scrollbars. Try to change Scrollmode to "scroll by items" as opposed to "scroll by pixels" in the abstract item view.. maybe that is enough to fix it.

Comment: You are right Johannes. 21,474,836 works fine but 21,474,837 does not (INT_MAX = 2,147,483,647). So there is some kind of the 'view' overflow(?).

Comment: With that many items, it might be better to cap the scroll range to INT_MAX and listen to QScrollBar actionTriggered signal for implementing left/right and page up/down. I've been down that road. Qt itemviews aren't suitable for displaying large amount of items by default.

Comment: tableView.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerItem); did not help. OK Johannes, thank you for hints.

Comment: Note: Qt's model-view architecture is limited to `INT_MAX` rows. You can work around that by flattening a tree and spreading the items to multiple parents. But the scroll view is still limited that way. Although you're not hitting that limit yet, you're only two orders of magnitude away. Perhaps you should redesign your UI -- for most people, lists with millions of items are useless.

Comment: And even more surprising is that the View allocates 500MB of RAM for a table with dimensions 20x20 millions. I thought one of the main motivation for Model-View pattern was to provide very resource efficient way (View) to look at data stored in Model. Now, Model just pretends to have a lot of data and View internally allocates 500MB. My world is falling apart.

Comment: @francek Check the section resize modes of the headers. QHeaderView tries to store contiguous sections that each have the same setting together as a "span" that takes constant memory regardless of the sections count. But you might have "resize to contents" active. Then I imagine it will allocate a size entry for each section. So, at least a couple of ints times 20M.

Comment: @Kuba Ober seems that maximum number of rows/columns in MV model is limited to INT_MAX divided by cell's height/width in pixels..for cell with size 30x100 pixels maximum nbr of rows is 71,582,788 and columns 21,474,836..with any numbers bigger than these example does not work..

Comment: @francek That's a limitation of Qt views, not the model. I should have been more explicit about that.

Comment: @Kuba Ober maybe Qt documentation should be more explicit ("The rowCount() and columnCount() functions return the dimensions of the table.") and mention that you need to take into account cell's dimensions